# Нужна помощь с классами

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++, структуры, конструктор

```
class sample
{
public:
    sample(int a) : c(a), next(0) {}
    int c;
    element *next;
};
```

Объясните пожалуйста, что значит эта строчка:

```
sample(int a) : c(a), next(0) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Инициализация переменных из конструктора, эквивалент:

```
sample(int a) 
{
    c = a;
    next = 0;    
}
```

Comment: Не совсем эквивалент. В вашем случае в начале будут вызваны конструкторы по умолчанию для c и next, а потом операторы присваивания.

В конструкторе класса после двоеточия перед телом конструктора можно (нужно если члены класса не имеют конструкторов по умолчанию) сконструировать члены, вызвав их конструкторы с необходимыми параметрами.

Обратите внимание, что создание членов класса идет не в том порядке как перечислены вызовы их конструкторов а в том как они объявлены в классе.

Answer (score 3):

Если обо всей строке, а не только о том, что между ":" и "{}", то это определение конструктора с пустым телом и инициализацией членов класса.